# How to retain Spark executor logs in Yarn after Spark application is crashed

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am trying to find the root cause of recent Spark application failure in production.  When the Spark application is running I can check NodeManager's yarn.nodemanager.log-dir property to get the Spark executor container logs.

The container has logs for both the running Spark applications

Here is the view of the container logs:
drwx--x--- 3 yarn yarn  51 Jul 19 09:04 application_1467068598418_0209
drwx--x--- 5 yarn yarn 141 Jul 19 09:04 application_1467068598418_0210

But when the application is killed both the application logs are automatically deleted.  I have set all the log retention setting etc in Yarn to a very large number.  But still these logs are deleted as soon as the Spark applications are crashed.

Question: How can we retain these Spark application logs in Yarn for debugging when the Spark application is crashed for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following location has executor logs.

```
HADOOP_USER_NAME=mapred hadoop fs -ls /hadoop/log/yarn/user/USER/logs/APPLICATION_ID
```

Also, set the following property :-

```
"yarn.log-aggregation-enable","false"
"spark.eventLog.enabled", "true"    
"spark.eventLog.dir","hdfs:///user/spark/applicationHistory"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I already have log aggregation enabled to true. And I am using Cloudera 5.5, I do not have any hadoop/yarn folder in HDFS.  How can i enable Yarn logging to save Spark executor logs in HDFS.

Comment: "spark.eventLog.enabled", "true" and "spark.eventLog.dir","hdfs:///user/spark/applicationHistory" by setting these two property we are able to see the executor logs in Spark History Server.